# How to add an item programmatically to the (System > Preferences > Startup Applications) in Linux?

Tags: linux

There are some ways to run automatically program on startup under Linux

But

My question is different.

I want to add a new item **programmatically** to the (System > Preferences > Startup Applications) in Linux. It means when I run my application, user see a new item under (System > Preferences > Startup Applications).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your .desktop file in this folder: ~/.config/autostart/

Comment: For which desktop environment/linux distributive this solution work?

Comment: @CAMOBAP I have tested this on Ubuntu with Unity. But I am pretty curtain that it will work on a lot of different distro's. Just go test it :)